# Modifier to only allow execution from a base class?

Tags: c#

If I have a class like this:

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    public abstract bool RunRemote();
    public abstract void RunLocal();
    public void Run()
    {
        if (RunRemote())
        {
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Data.db;Version=3;");
            connection.Open();

            var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE Actions SET Complete = 1 WHERE Id = @Id", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Id", Id));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        RunLocal();
    }
}
```

What I want is to only expose Run() as public, but abstract and virtual cannot be marked as private. Is there a clean way of doing this (e.g. not using delegates etc.)

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: What about the Visitor pattern?

Comment: Do you want to only allow objects of the base class to call your Run() method, or do you mean you only want the base class implementation of `Run()` to be allowed.

Comment: That's precisely what `protected` is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `protected`. That will allow the base class or derived classes to access the methods.

```
protected abstract bool RunRemote();
protected abstract void RunLocal();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public abstract class ActionBase
    {
        protected abstract bool RunRemote();
        protected abstract void RunLocal();

        public void Run()
        {
            if (RunRemote())
            {
                // ....
            }
            RunLocal();
        }
    }
```

or somehting.